# JQuery AutoComplete NOT working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have this JQuery using AJAX:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type ="text/javascript">
   var data = "";
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tbSearch").change(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "AgentList.aspx/LoadData",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                   data = msg.d.split(" ");
                   $("#tbSearch").autocomplete("minLength", 0);
                   $("#tbSearch").autocomplete("search", "");
                   $("#tbSearch").autocomplete("AgentList.aspx/LoadData");

               }
           });
       });
   });

    </script>
```

And this is the function which is displaying what should be there in autocomplete:

```
#region "Auto Complete"
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string[] LoadData()
    {
        string[] arra = new string[] {"Small", "Money", "People", "So", "Some", "Rome", "Test", "John", "Angel", "J", "Damn you"};
        return arra;

    }
    #endregion
```

My JQ is not firing even. I dont know what is wrong here :(